# How to Include model data in Spark Java response for React JS to access?

Tags: java, json, reactjs, spark-java

I'm building a web app with Spark Java, OrientDB, and hopefully React.

With Spark Java and Velocity templates, I can access the server side data in the template and do my rendering logic based off of that. Since React is client side, how do I include that same data-model with the response so that I don't have to go back to the server with AJAX?

If I convert my POJO/Map/List to JSON, how can I include that data with the initial HTML/React without going back to the server to fetch it?

Comment: maybe this will give you some ideas http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/02/16/isomorphic-react-webapps-on-the-jvm/

Answer (score 1):

You should output an html script tag containing a javascript variable with your JSON serialized data.

Something like this:

```
<script>
window.myData = $myData;
</script>
```

Then you can access these data client side.

Comment: I will try this. Thanks.